# Why invokedynamic-based String concatenation is not available for javac in java.base

Tags: java, string, performance, string-concatenation

Once I recklessly [tried](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/3464) to optimize `Class.resolveName()` relying on the results of
benchmark (available in the referenced PR) replicating the logic of the mentioned method. The idea of optimization was quite trivial and about replacing `new StringBuilder().append()` with plain concatenation. It turned out that while the benchmark demonstrated significant improvement, the patched method itself regressed. As [it was pointed out](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/3464#issuecomment-818827786) in comments of the PR

> The JMH test may show better results as it is compiled to bytecode that
> uses special invokedynamic-based string concatenation with optimal MH
> based underlying strategy. The code in java.lang.Class can't be compiled
> to use this kind of concatenation because of bootstrapping issues and is
> therefore compiled to bytecode that uses StringBuilder directly (much
> like the existing code of the patched method).

Indeed, concatenation of Strings in `java.base` is compiled into `StringBuilder`-based bytecode unlike it is done for client code (there they utilize `invokedynamic` together with `StringConcatFactory`).

I've investigated those 'bootstrapping issues' but the only thing that I've found is about the order of class loading. If one runs `java -Xlog:class+init -version` it becomes clear that `StringConcatFactory` is loaded far after `j.l.Class`. At the same time there are lots of other classes referenced from `j.l.Class` loaded after it either.

So my question is why `javac` can use e. g. `StringBuilder` within `Class.resolveName()`, but not `StringConcatFactory`? What is so special about that class?

Or maybe my speculation is wrong and the bootstrapping issue is not about `StringConcatFactory` and `invokedynamic`?

Comment: `StringBuilder` relies on _much_ less of the Java language and library infrastructure than `StringConcatFactory`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman good guess! Then I thought about `MethodHanldes` which relies on even more broad infrastructure but still loaded as number 27

Comment: This is to avoid cyclic dependency. `StringConcatFactory` relies on JSR 292 machinery, which in turn uses many java.base classes that use string concatenation.

Comment: @apangin thanks for explanation! Can you add your comment as an answer to this question so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bootstrapping issues" here is the problem of the chicken or the egg.

`StringConcatFactory` relies on JSR 292 machinery, which in turn uses `java.base` classes that use string concatenation. In order to resolve this cyclic dependency, concatenation is `java.base` classes is compiled in an old-fashioned way that does not depend on `StringConcatFactory`.