# Optimizations of "+" operand for strings in JDK 17

Tags: dart, java, javac, bytecode

We know that in JDK8 and below, strings using a plus sign for concatenation will be compiled into StringBuilder for performance optimization, but after JDK9, it will be implemented using the `java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory#makeConcatWithConstants` method.

However, after decompiling `java.lang.Object`, it can be seen that its `toString` method is still implemented using StringBuilder:

```
public java.lang.String toString();
descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: new           #1                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
     3: dup
     4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
     7: aload_0
     8: invokevirtual #7                  // Method getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
    11: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/lang/Class.getName:()Ljava/lang/String;
    14: invokevirtual #19                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    17: ldc           #23                 // String @
    19: invokevirtual #19                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    22: aload_0
    23: invokevirtual #25                 // Method hashCode:()I
    26: invokestatic  #29                 // Method java/lang/Integer.toHexString:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
    29: invokevirtual #19                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    32: invokevirtual #35                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
    35: areturn
  LineNumberTable:
    line 256: 0
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      36     0  this   Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Looking through the source code, it can be seen that it still uses the plus sign to connect the three parts:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Rewrite the same code into a class to compile:

```
public class Main {
    public String fooString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
}
```

It can be seen from the decompilation that it is still implemented using the `java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory#makeConcatWithConstants` method:

```
public java.lang.String fooString();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
        start local 0 // Main this
         0: aload_0
         1: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
         4: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/lang/Class.getName:()Ljava/lang/String;
         7: aload_0
         8: invokevirtual #17                 // Method java/lang/Object.hashCode:()I
        11: invokestatic  #21                 // Method java/lang/Integer.toHexString:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
        14: invokedynamic #27,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:makeConcatWithConstants:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        19: areturn
        end local 0 // Main this
      LineNumberTable:
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      20     0  this   LMain;
```

So why is the plus sign used in `Object` class implemented using `StringBuilder` while class `A`(mentioned above) using `makeConcatWithConstants`? Does the bytecode of the Object class provided by the JDK do not match the source code, or is there a special optimization for the Object class at compile time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71834059/why-invokedynamic-based-string-concatenation-is-not-available-for-javac-in-java

Comment: Why does this question have a 'dart' tag? I see it didn't have that tag when created. It seems not possible to remove. Weird.

Comment: @Lii You're not the first one to notice. It's being discussed [here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421265/why-is-this-question-shown-with-a-tag-dart-it-doesnt-have).

Answer (score 24):

It's explained in [the JEP](https://openjdk.org/jeps/280). Emphasis mine

> java.base exemptions. Since this feature uses a core library feature
> (java.lang.invoke) to implement a core language feature (String
> concatenation), we have to exempt the java.base module from using the
> indified String concat. **Otherwise a circularity happens** when the
> java.lang.invoke.* machinery requires String concat to work, which in
> turn requires the java.lang.invoke.* machinery. This exemption may
> limit the performance improvements observed from this feature, since
> many java.base classes will not be able to use it. We consider this an
> acceptable downside, which should be covered by the VM's optimizing
> compilers.